# During the first call, I get the no_data_found error. And that is logical. Because the tables are empty. how can this be fixed?

Tags: sql, plsql

I tried using EXCEPTION but it doesn't work as I would like.
And it doesn't seem like a good solution to me.

EXCEPTION
when no_data_found then
v_current_elec_social_reading := 0;

I don't know how to solve it any other way.

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY pkg_meter_reading IS

    PROCEDURE add_reading_e_prod IS

        v_random_e_prod                    elec_prod.power_kwh%TYPE := dbms_random.value(0, 2000);
        v_current_elec_prod_reading        elec_prod.meter_reading_kwh%TYPE;
    BEGIN


        SELECT
            meter_reading_kwh

        INTO v_current_elec_prod_reading
        FROM
            elec_prod
        ORDER BY
            date_measurement DESC
        FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;

        dbms_output.put_line(v_current_elec_prod_reading);
        INSERT INTO elec_prod (
            id_meter,
            date_measurement,
            meter_reading_kwh,
            power_kwh
        ) VALUES (
            11,
            sysdate,
            v_current_elec_prod_reading + v_random_e_prod / 12,
            v_random_e_prod
        );



    END add_reading_e_prod;


PROCEDURE add_reading_e_social IS

        v_random_e_social                       elec_social.power_kwh%TYPE := dbms_random.value(0, 2000);
        v_current_elec_social_reading           elec_social.meter_reading_kwh%TYPE;
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            meter_reading_kwh
        INTO v_current_elec_social_reading
        FROM
            elec_social
        ORDER BY
            date_measurement DESC
        FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;

        dbms_output.put_line(v_current_elec_social_reading);
        INSERT INTO elec_social (
            id_meter,
            date_measurement,
            meter_reading_kwh,
            power_kwh
        ) VALUES (
            131,
            sysdate,
            v_current_elec_social_reading + v_random_e_social/12,
            v_random_e_social
        );


    END add_reading_e_social;


END pkg_meter_reading;
```

I tried using EXCEPTION but it doesn't work as I would like.
And it doesn't seem like a good solution to me.

EXCEPTION
when no_data_found then
v_current_elec_social_reading := 0;

I don't know how to solve it any other way.

Comment: You could also just use `INSERT...SELECT with ROW_NUMBER()` in one statement unless you really have to split the work into two statements (maybe you want to do something else with the results of the first statement before inserting. This would avoid having to use FETCH and its no_data_found error.

Answer (score 1):

You said you tried to use exception handling section, but - why didn't you post it? *Where* did you put it? Should've probably been in an **inner** `BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END` block, not at procedure level because it wouldn't "fix" anything - insert won't happen.

Something like this (the same goes for both procedures).

Sample table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE elec_prod
  2  (
  3     id_meter            NUMBER,
  4     date_measurement    DATE,
  5     meter_reading_kwh   NUMBER,
  6     power_kwh           NUMBER
  7  );

Table created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_reading_e_prod
  2  IS
  3     v_random_e_prod              elec_prod.power_kwh%TYPE := DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (0, 2000);
  4     v_current_elec_prod_reading  elec_prod.meter_reading_kwh%TYPE;
  5  BEGIN
  6     BEGIN                                                       --> inner block starts here
  7          SELECT meter_reading_kwh
  8            INTO v_current_elec_prod_reading
  9            FROM elec_prod
 10        ORDER BY date_measurement DESC
 11           FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
 12     EXCEPTION
 13        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
 14        THEN
 15           v_current_elec_prod_reading := 0;
 16     END;                                                          --> inner block ends here
 17
 18     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_current_elec_prod_reading);
 19
 20     INSERT INTO elec_prod (id_meter,
 21                            date_measurement,
 22                            meter_reading_kwh,
 23                            power_kwh)
 24          VALUES (11,
 25                  SYSDATE,
 26                  v_current_elec_prod_reading + v_random_e_prod / 12,
 27                  v_random_e_prod);
 28  END add_reading_e_prod;
 29  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing: first execution:

```
SQL> EXEC add_reading_e_prod;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT * FROM elec_prod;

  ID_METER DATE_MEASUREMENT    METER_READING_KWH  POWER_KWH
---------- ------------------- ----------------- ----------
        11 30.10.2023 07:09:37        152,728356 1832,74027
```

Second execution:

```
SQL> EXEC add_reading_e_prod;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT * FROM elec_prod;

  ID_METER DATE_MEASUREMENT    METER_READING_KWH  POWER_KWH
---------- ------------------- ----------------- ----------
        11 30.10.2023 07:09:37        152,728356 1832,74027
        11 30.10.2023 07:09:56        230,574188  934,14998

SQL>
```

Therefore, yes - inner block handles it.

Comment: I tried in 2 places. At the end of the procedure and in the middle. At the end it didn't make an insert at all.
And when I put EXCEPTION in the middle, when the exeption didn't occur, it didn't make an insert either.

Comment: It should have. Could you post (by editing the original question) some more info about that - possibly your SQL*Plus session which illustrates it?

Comment: I edited the answer and posted whole test case. It shows that inner block does help. If you failed, well, that's probably up to you. If you posted what you exactly did, perhaps we could help with it.

Comment: ok, I found a mistake.
Your code is good. thanks

Comment: Is this a good solution?
I'm not sure, but I think I heard somewhere not to put logic in the EXCEPTION section?
Can you give me an idea for another solution?
Maybe this can be done in CASE?